# Batch Request to Asana API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, asana, asana-api

I for some reason can't get the formatting to work when I submit a Batch API request to the Asana API. Below are 2 sections, the first of which is how I normally would send a single request to the Asana API, as well as their documentation for how to do so, so that you can see how my code relates to what they specify. The second section is my attempt at submitting a batch request and again their documentation of how to do so.

**Single Request**

[Their documentation here](https://developers.asana.com/docs/create-a-task)

My code (works perfectly)

```
const url1 = baseURL + '/tasks'

const payload1 =
{
  name: 'Test Task 1',
  projects: projectGID,
}

const options1 =
{
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  payload: payload1,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
}

const resp1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options1)

Logger.log(resp1)
```

**Batch Request**

[Their Batch Request Documentation](https://developers.asana.com/docs/submit-parallel-requests)
(can scroll up a bit from this link to get more info if needed)

My code (error message: "Bad Request")

```
const url2 = baseURL + '/batch'

const payload2 =
{
  actions:
  [
    {
      data:
      {
        name: 'Test Task 1',
        projects: projectGID
      },
      method: "post",
      relative_path: "/tasks"
    },
    {
      data:
      {
        name: 'Test Task 2',
        projects: projectGID
      },
      method: "post",
      relative_path: "/tasks"
    }
  ]
}

const options2 =
{
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  payload: payload2,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
}

const resp2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2)

Logger.log(resp2)
```

Comment: As per docs: `Like other POST endpoints, the body should contain a data envelope` So, you have to wrap your `actions` in a data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From [your provided official document](https://developers.asana.com/docs/submit-parallel-requests), you want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl -X POST https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/batch \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -H 'Accept: application/json' \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer {access-token}' \
      -d '{"data":{"actions":[{"data":{"assignee":"me","workspace":"1337"},"method":"get","options":{"fields":["name","notes","completed"],"limit":3},"relative_path":"/tasks/123"}]}}'
  ```

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your request body, it seems that it is required to be modified.
- When I saw the sample curl command, it seems that the request body is required to be sent with the content type of "application/json".
- In your script, `projectGID` and `headers` are not declared.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const projectGID = "###"; // Please set your value.
  const headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ###", // Please set your access token.
    "Accept": "application/json",
  }
  const url2 = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/batch";

  const payload2 = { // Modified
    data: {
      actions:
        [
          {
            data:
            {
              name: 'Test Task 1',
              projects: projectGID
            },
            method: "post",
            relative_path: "/tasks"
          },
          {
            data:
            {
              name: 'Test Task 2',
              projects: projectGID
            },
            method: "post",
            relative_path: "/tasks"
          }
        ]
    }
  };
  const options2 = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload2), // Modified
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    contentType: "application/json", // Added
  }
  const resp2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2)
  Logger.log(resp2)
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, I think that the request is the same as the sample curl command. But, if an error occurs, please confirm your values in the request body and your access token, again.

#### References:

- [Submit parallel requests](https://developers.asana.com/docs/submit-parallel-requests)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: I had also tried adding the data wrapper previously, but it only threw me a new error.  I also neglected to paste my headers variable, but it is in fact there in my script and it specifies "Accept": "application/json" However, when I used stringify on the payload as you did, and specified contentType: "application/json" in the options object, as well as adding the data wrapper, that did the trick! Had to do all 3 things, an omission of any of the 3 resulted in an error. Thank you!

Comment: @Chandler Catron Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.